# Query rewrite php

Tags: php, string, url-rewriting

I am using this PHP element to add spelling suggestions to my search engine.
So far it half works.

The issue is when I click on the suggestion I want to populate my search box and execute another query.

I have tried editing the code a lot but seem to be blind to the issue.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(0); 

if ($_POST['query']) { 
    $query = ($_POST['query']);
    $q_words = explode (" ", $query);
    $loop_count = 0;
    $q_count = count($q_words);
    $s_count = 0;
    $ss_count = 0;
    echo ('<h4>Did you mean ....?</h4>');
    while ($loop_count <= $q_count ) {
        $query = 'http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/'.$q_words[$loop_count].'?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXX85a'; $xml = new SimpleXMLIterator(file_get_contents($query));

        foreach ($xml -> suggestion as $suggestion[$s_count]) {
            $s_count++;
        }

        if ($s_count > 1) {
            while ($ss_count <=$s_count) {
                echo '<a href = "Wedn.php?query='.$q_words[$loop_count-1].' '.$suggestion[$ss_count].'">'.$q_words[$loop_count-1].' '.$suggestion[$ss_count].'</a><br>';
                $ss_count++; 
            }
        }

        $loop_count++; 
    } 
}
?>
```

I'm getting the following error messages:

> Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in /home/msc2012/04665236/public_html/WEB-INF/bootstrap/rewrite.php on line 23

and

> Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in /home/msc2012/04665236/public_html/WEB-INF/bootstrap/rewrite.php on line 25

Comment: You can start by turning error reporting on. Also, what happens _instead_ of what you want?

Comment: Ok I turned error reporting on. What is currently happening is if you miss spell a word it offers you alternatives which are links, the concept being you can click on them and a new query will be sent to the search engine. Currently when I click upon the suggested word the page reloads but the query is not sent

Comment: errors being shown:  Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in /home/msc2012/04665236/public_html/WEB-INF/bootstrap/rewrite.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in /home/msc2012/04665236/public_html/WEB-INF/bootstrap/rewrite.php on line 25

Comment: Good. Now [edit] your question to include these errors and the corresponding lines of code (lines 23 - 25). Leave the current code block in place though. Do this anytime you post a question so we can better determine what's going on. A big block of code doesn't help much if we don't know what happens, what you expected to happen, and any related error messages.

Comment: Much better, but in the future you should also indicate which lines those errors correspond to, since we can't tell from the code block. Nevertheless, good question and welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your link "Href" URL cannot have spaces in its query

```
echo '<a href = "Wedn.php?query='.$q_words[$loop_count-1].'_'.$suggestion[$ss_count].'">'
             .$q_words[$loop_count-1].' '.$suggestion[$ss_count]
    .'</a><br>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but does not seem to of made a difference. Its seems to be failing to input the new query into the search box.

Comment: My apology the space is allowed in the query element of a URL

Answer (score 0):

On your first loop, you are trying to get `$q_words[-1]`, as `$loop_count = 0` so `$q_words[$loop_count-1]`=>`$q_words[-1]`

```
$loop_count = 0;
...
while ($loop_count <= $q_count ) {
    ...
    if ($s_count > 1) {
        while ($ss_count <=$s_count) {
            echo '<a href = "Wedn.php?query='.$q_words[$loop_count-1].' '.$suggestion[$ss_count].'">'.$q_words[$loop_count-1].' '.$suggestion[$ss_count].'</a><br>';
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            $ss_count++; 
        }
    }

    $loop_count++; 
}
```

I think you want to change both of those to `$q_words[$loop_count]`